# Can not replace Shimano Octalink with 105 Crankset

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket

[image: octalink old bb]

[image: 105 left leg]

Hello! I am trying to upgrade my bike’s Octalink BB 118 mm to a 105 5600 BB and crankset. The problem is I can not make the plastic pin of 105 left leg fit the hole. I think the axle is too short or BB is too wide? Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Road/Mountain Hollowtech II Bottom Brackets?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47334/difference-between-road-mountain-hollowtech-ii-bottom-brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your shell width. Shimano road cranks only work with 68mm shells and require 'road' version of the Hollowtech BB. (MTB cranks / MTB BBs work with 68 and 73mm shells.) I think it's likely you have a 73mm shell.

See [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/47334/24228) for details on the difference between road and MTB BBs.

Update: just looked at the pic of your old BB and it is in fact marked '73'.

Comment: Thanks @argenti! My bike is a road bike come with Octalink BB and Claris crank, seem not much choices for upgrade?